# How to export a specific cell to text files in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a file need to export to tet or html file, I want column A to be the file name, and column B to be the content of that file.

I have this which successfully exports one row to one text file:

```
function saveToTextfile() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
var rows = range.getValues();
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("folderName").next();
var files = folder.getFiles();
while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
  folder.createFile("row" + index + ".txt", row.join(", "));
});
}
```

Is it possible to add a column just as reference for file name, but not include in the export file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
function saveToTextfile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 2);
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folderid')
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  vs.forEach(r => folder.createFile(r[0] + '.txt', r[1]) );
}
```